# How to configure react js environment to instantly compile to a specific directory?

Tags: webpack, build, configuration, package.json, createjs

I have a php server, inside the server there is a directory in which I place my application. When npm start starts, the application starts in developer mode and changes are tracked with instant compilation. This method causes a lot of problems and starts an unnecessary server with port 3000.
I need to make the compilation to a folder and optionally with a hot restart, the main thing is that on my apache / php server I can easily see the output of the compiled application. And with the changes, the necessary parts were recompiled. Without starting a new server.
I don’t have time to understand the configurations, please tell me how it can be done and is there a ready-made instruction for this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have set up React using create-react-app.

If you did, and you want to just compile the changes, you can do that using [`npm run build`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-build). It will compile a production build of the app into the "build" folder.

If you would like some sort of "watch" mode, where the app is automatically rebuilt whenever there are changes to the source files, you'd have to either add some custom scripts like [this one](https://gist.github.com/int128/e0cdec598c5b3db728ff35758abdbafd), or switch to  [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), which will require a bit of learning curve. If you do, I suggest cloning one of these [starter setups](https://webpack.js.org/starter-kits/) and customising them.